# Is it possible to renew MCSD SharePoint 2013 certifications by just watching courses?

Tags: certification

Is it possible to renew MCSD SharePoint 2013 certifications by just watching courses ?

Few years ago, one was able to renew there certifications for MCSD for SharePoint 2013 by watching courses online, does anyone knows if it still works ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, that was never possible. Microsoft technical certifications require either upgrade exams or new exams. (There may have been other options for end-user "certifications".)

Several online courses offered extra cost certificates (like edX) but they were only proof of attendance, not certification.